# Firebase connection to console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I have a problem that I can access the console at work , but when I go to home I cannot access the console and a message appears that there are some errors .

Because of we can only contact someone from Firebase for just 5 times in a year, I decided to ask here instead.

Does any one know anything about this situation or what causes it or how to avoid it?
[image: the error message]

Comment: The project are yours?

Comment: yes , they are mine this is the console page